# Rooted Phone's data folder now empty

Tags: sqlite

I used to see all the dbs in File Explorer , now all of a sudden the data folder is empty, What could have happened?

Phone: Motorola Droid X (original). I have been debugging rigorously, the only other thing I did is set up a write to my sdcard from my code and I CAN see that in File Explorer.....

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you did before this happened?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I didn't change any settings on the physical phone if that's what you mean.

Comment: If it were actually empty, the phone wouldn't work.  I'd a reboot and clearing the data for your file explorer.

Comment: I rebooted phone, & still nothing underneath data folder, hmmmmm....

Comment: did you used to have root and now you don't? if you dont have root, you wont be able to see in that directory. Or maybe the permissions have changed on /data. As @MatthewRead stated, if it was empty, nothing would work.

Comment: I did not explicitly "un-root" the phone, can you actually do that? Also why would permissions have changed? If they have changed, how do I set up admin access?

Comment: If "File Explorer" refers to an app on the Android device: Did you check whether it is (still) granted superuser permission (check that with the *SuperUser* or *SuperSU* app, it should be listed there)? Maybe you accidentally removed the permission. In that case, the data folders might *appear* empty. Same thing as Ryan meant. And for the records: Yes, un-rooting is also possible.